# Conectar Android mediante usb. adb devices errores varios (xxxxxxxxxx no permissions) OS tipo UNIX

Tags: android

Tratando de conectar un dispositivo android estoy teniendo errores del tipo:

command shell:

```
./adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

command shell:

```
./adb devices
List of devices attached
xxxxxxxxxxxx    no permissions
```

Comment: hacia tiempo que no obtenia este error y se me ocurrio crea una respuesta general, pues casi no recordaba como solucionarlos y si habia hecho algo mal al agregar el dispositivo. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si nunca antes a podido usar el `adb` puede tratar de configurarlo de la manera que se muestra a continuacion, si por el contrario es un error puntual puede ir al final de la respuesta, y probar alguna de las soluciones que se mencionen:

**-1.** Creamos el siguiente fichero como root.

```
touch /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

**-2.**

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

**-3.** Ahora con el fichero creado lo abrimos con un editor de manera que podamos editar en el para añadir algunas lineas con el siguiente este formato:

```
#x-x-x-x-x-x
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxxx", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

El `ATTR{idVendor}==”xxxx”` Cambiaremos el `“xxxx”` por el codigo que corresponda a nuestro dispositivo, en este punto puedes obtenerlo de dos manera.

---

La primera la que considero mas rapida usando el comando lsusb, si no cuentas con el puede bajarlo, pero no es necesario, si optas por no bajarlo puedes hacerlo de la segunda manera que esta mas abajo.

---

**Primera manera.**

Lanzamos `lsusb` en la Shell y otendremos algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
lsusb
//..
Bus 001 Device 006: ID xxxx:xxxx ............................... 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 12d1:1038 Huawei Technologies Co.........
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0333:0330 ...........................
//..
```

Buscamos la linea donde nos muestra el dispositivo que vamos a agregar, si no esta tan claro conectamos y desconectamos usando `lsusb` entre ellas, para ver cual es.

Tomamos el primer numero despues del ID en este caso es 12d1.
Y es el que aplicamos al formato que escribimos en el fichero.

fichero -> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
#Huawei
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

---

**Segunda Manera.**

Buscas la marca del fabricante en la siguiente lista la copias o escribes en el fichero /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

```
#Acer
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#ASUS
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Dell
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Foxconn
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Fujitsu & Fujitsu Toshiba
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Garmin-Asus
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Google
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Haier
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="201e", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Hisense
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="109b", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Huawei
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#K-Touch
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#KT Tech
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Kyocera
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Lenovo
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#LG
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Motorola
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#MTK
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#NEC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Nook
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Nvidia
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#OTGV
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Pantech
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Pegatron
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Philips
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#PMC-Sierra
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Qualcomm
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#SK Telesys
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sharp
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sony
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sony Ericsson
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Teleepoch
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2340", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#Toshiba
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#ZTE
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
#ZUK
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2b4c", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

fichero /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules para un dispositivo `Huawei` seria la siguente.

```
#Huawei
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

---

**-4.** Verificamos que tu usuario (normal no como root) esta dentro del grupo `plugdev` con el comando `groups` si no se encuentra lo agregamos.

**-5.** Ahora vamos al directorio donde tenemos el `Home/Android/Sdk/tools` y creamos el fichero `adb_usb.ini` esto lo hacemos como usuario normal y escribimos dentro de el lo siguiente:

```
0x12d1
```

y guardamos, el numero `12d1` corresponde al mismo que usamos anteriormente de ser otro pues seria `0x????`.De introducir o tener varios dispositivos se agregara uno por linea en el mismo fichero.

**-6.** En es directorio `Home/Android/Sdk/tools` ejecutamos lo siguiente:

`./android update adb`

**-7.** Ahora con permisos de superUser:

```
@:/home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb kill-server
@:/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
@:/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb devices
List of devices attached
3xxxxxxxxxx device
```

fuentes -> http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

---

Si ya lo tenias configurado puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Ahora con permisos de superUser:

```
@:/home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb kill-server
@:/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
@:/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools# ./adb devices
List of devices attached
3xxxxxxxxxx device
```

Comment: En el pasado ya lo habia configurado pero son de esas cosas que uno o por lo menos a mi me sucedio, lo hace una vez y hasta que vuelva hacerlas de nuevo quizas pasen años. Puedes agregar soluciones o modificar la pregunta si creer que es nesesario Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que funcione rápido vas a la carpeta donde está ubicado adb y lo detienes:

```
./adb kill-server
```

Luego lo vuelves a iniciar pero con permisos de superusuario:

```
sudo ./adb start-server
```

Al momento de revisar los dispositivos conectados te debería funcionar bien